# How to sort an array of alpha-numeric strings -using java 7

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, automation

I tried `collection.sort` and hash maps but it is sorting it in dictionary 
order. this array is list of web-elements text.

Scenario : my application is providing these values in a sorted manner and i need to verify that.so i am picking these values in an array list....and further i tried .......using collection sort ...its not working

Array need to be sorted

```
[A01B, A01D41, A23G4, A41D19, A43B1, A43B1, A43B13, A43B13, A43B5, A43B5, A43B7, A43C1, A46B, A46B1, A46B15]
```

Expected Array

```
 [A01B,A01D41,A23G4,A41D19,A43B1,A43B1,A43B5,A43B5,A43B7,A43B13,A43B13,A43C1,A46B,A46B1,A46B15]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: That's because, alphanumerically, string like **A43B13** is before **A43B7**, because of the 1 after the B (which is lower than the 7): you have to implement a custom comparator

Comment: Please post your solution so that we can check..

Comment: Well, I have a solution that I will now have to post as a comment without the code formatting and syntax highlighting. See below.

Comment: @Stultuske : i tried this code --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169234/how-to-sort-alphanumeric-string  but it is not working as desired -----using this code i am getting output :[A01B,A01D41,A23G4,A41D19,A43B1,A43B1,A43B13,A43B13,A43B5,A43B5,A43B7,A43C1,A46B,A46B1,A46B15]   which is as similar to output using simply collection.sort()

Comment: @Leviand: i tried using comparator<String> via lambda expression and it worked for me but as per my framework i am bounded to used java 7 .can you provide custom compactor logic compatible with java 7.