# Sorting of alphanumeric in java

Tags: java, sorting, alphanumeric

I want to sort alpha-numeric values as if my input is

```
[a1, b1, c1, aa1, bb1, cc1, d1, e1]
```

Output should be in this order- `a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,aa1,bb1,cc1`

I have used this code

```
public class coll {

    public static int comparator(String s1, String s2) {

        String[] pt1 = s1.split("((?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]))"); 
        String[] pt2 = s2.split("((?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]))"); 
//pt1 and pt2 arrays will have the string split in alphabets and numbers

        int i=0;
        if(Arrays.equals(pt1, pt2))
            return 0;
        else{
            for(i=0;i<Math.min(pt1.length, pt2.length);i++)
                if(!pt1[i].equals(pt2[i])) {
                    if(!isNumber(pt1[i],pt2[i])) {
                        if(pt1[i].compareTo(pt2[i])>0)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        int nu1 = Integer.parseInt(pt1[i]);
                        int nu2 = Integer.parseInt(pt2[i]);
                        if(nu1>nu2)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return -1;
                    }
                }
        }

        if(pt1.length>i)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    private static Boolean isNumber(String n1, String n2) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            int nu1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
            int nu2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception x) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] examples = {"a1", "b1", "c1", "aa1", "bb1", "cc1", "d1", "e1"};
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(examples));

        System.out.println(values);
        Comparator<String> com = (o1,o2) -> {return comparator(o1,o2);}; //lambda expression

        Collections.sort(values,com);
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

output is `[a1, aa1, b1, bb1, c1, cc1, d1, e1]`

But , I want

```
[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,aa1,bb1,cc1]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You forgot to add your code?

Comment: try this out. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27169507/5250973

Comment: @JayDangar how do you know this is what he wants?

Comment: That is not alpha-numeric order... If it would be instead of `a1, b1, .. aa1` you would get `a1, aa1, ...  b1`. Explain logic you are using to decide your desired output.

Comment: I dont know that logic thats why , i am asking here.

Comment: What about `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: @Nix So, you want to first sort by length and then just sort strings?

Comment: Then how do you know that result should be `[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,aa1,bb1,cc1]` and not `[a1, aa1, b1, bb1, c1, cc1, d1, e1]`? There must be *some* logic which you are using to decide that.

Comment: @Wow yeah exactly

Comment: @Nix, okay, look at my answer

Comment: @Wow Thank you :)

Comment: only for curiosity, what if input is ("a1", "b1", "c1",,"a0111","d1","b11","a101","a11", "aa1", "bb1", "e1", "aaa1) and we want output as a1,a11,a101,a0111,b1,b11,c1,d1,e1,aa1,bb1,aaa1

Comment: @Nix output become `[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, a11, aa1, b11, bb1, c01, c11, cc1, a101, aaa1, a0111]
`

Comment: @soorapadman what can we do if we want output as a1,a11,a101,a0111,b1,b11,c1,d1,e1,aa1,bb1,aaa1. What will be logic

Answer (score 7):

From the looks of it, this is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a1", "b1", "c1", "aa1", "bb1", "cc1", "aaa1", "d1", "e1"));
    a.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

you first sort by length, then sort strings in length groups.

The output is:
`[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, aa1, bb1, cc1, aaa1]`

Java 7 version:

```
Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null) return -1;
        else if (o2 == null) return 1;
        int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
        if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

Both of the above code examples are null-safe.

Comment: Thank you @Wow  :)

Comment: `thenComparing(Function.identity())` may be a bit confusing. `thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())` is more readable IMO or even `thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` if we don't want to see `a` and `A` as different characters.

Comment: What if ,we want output as a1,a11,a101,a0111,b1,b11,c1,d1,e1,aa1,bb1,aaa1. What will be logic @Wow

Comment: @Nix you need to specify the language of your strings. I suspect it is [a-z]*[0-9]*. It is unclear if a0111 is greater than or less than a111.

Comment: sorry for that. but yes in this a0111 is greater than a111 @Wow. I want to arrange it in alphabetical order .i.e. a1,a11,a111,b1,c1,aa1,bb1

Comment: @Nix okay, then you need to split your strings into 2 parts, the first part is going to be the letter part and the second part is going to be the digit part, then have this chain of comparisons: for any 2 strings 1) compare the letter parts, 2) then compare the lengths of the digit parts, 3) then convert the digit parts into int's, using Integer.parseInt() and compare them, using Integer.compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also `String::length` then `String::compareToIgnoreCase`

```
String[] examples = {"a1", "b1", "c1", "aa1", "bb1", "cc1", "aaa1", "d1", "e1"};
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(examples));
values.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareToIgnoreCase));
System.out.println(values);
```

Output

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, aa1, bb1, cc1, aaa1]
```