# How to sort alphabet and number

Tags: java

In my coding I am getting sorted output based on the name. But if I put same name then array remain same. Is there any way, when name is same then number will be sorted? Thanks in advance.

```java
 public class InsertionSort {

           /*Function to sort array using insertion sort*/
            void sort(String str[]) 
            { 
                int n = str.length; 
                for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) 
                { 
                    String key = str[i]; 
                    int j = i-1; 

                    /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are 
                       greater than key, to one position ahead 
                       of their current position */
                    while (j >= 0 && key.compareTo(str[j]) < 0)  
                    { 
                        str[j+1] = str[j]; 
                        j = j-1; 
                    } 
                    str[j+1] = key; 
                } 
            } 

            /* A utility function to print array of size n*/
            static void printArray(String str[]) 
            { 
                int n = str.length; 
                for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
                    System.out.print(str[i] + " "); 

                System.out.println(); 
            } 

            // Driver method 
            public static void main(String args[]) 
            {         
                 String[]  str ={"asif44","asif435"}; //2 elements



                printArray(str); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: you have an array of strings, so far so good. what does not work? which "numbers" do you mean? do you mean the numbers contained in the strings? if so, you clearly have to split the values and then 2 step comparison, otherwise it's just lexicographical sorting that happens on strings

Comment: i mean the number after the name.. such as asif44

Comment: yes, I saw this. You have to split the strings first into part1 and part2, then you can do the comparison, first comparing part1 as string comparison, then part2 as number comparison.

Comment: here is the regex to split the strings by word number boundary: `String regex = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)";` - the rest is up to you and pretty much straightforward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Alphanumeric String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169234/how-to-sort-alphanumeric-string)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more  precised way to do the same, add the string elements in and collection framework data type and use collections.sort() method.

Answer (score -1):

you are not calling the sort() method in your code. Also, you will need to make sort() method static to be able to call from main() method.

```
  // Driver method 
            public static void main(String args[]) 
            {         
                 String[]  str ={"asif44","asif435"}; //2 elements

                 **sort(str);**

                printArray(str); 
            }
```

Comment: that is not the answer ... he has to split the string into two parts in order to sort first part by string comparison, second part by number compariosn

Comment: @AKSW please you can take the code , execute and confirm.

Comment: @AKSW are you sure? I think string compare takes that into account. Also Arrays.sort also does this

Comment: I don't have to comfirm what I know. strings are sorted lexicographically, it wouldn't sort it into the right order based on the number part contained inside the string

Comment: @StephanHogenboom I'm sure, yes. Lexicogrpahical order vs number order is different, isn't it? what about "4" vs "15"? what comes first as String, and what if you compare plain numbers?

Comment: lexicographically as well, 43 will always come before 44. I can simply say just execute the code and test out for yourself

Comment: here for you guys the sample code: `System.out.println(Integer.compare(4, 15));
        System.out.println("4".compareTo("15"));` - obviously, the order is different ...